# Thunderbird and Dovecot, INBOX is not synchronized on multiple pcs

Tags: dovecot, imap, thunderbird

i have a little problem with Thunderbird mail and Dovecot. I use the the latest stable from Thunderbird and connect my mail account about the IMAP protocol.

Now i have an office PC and a Notebook, on both systems are the same Thunderbird installed and the settings are 1:1 the same (i have copy the profile folder, to be sure) :-)

The problem is, when i mark a mail as seen (+flag) or unseen (-flag) on the PC or Notebook, the other thunderbird does not sync this event and nothing happens. For example, both systems are here at the moment, i open the Thunderbird and look into my inbox folder. There are 25 mails and 0 are unread. Now, if i mark a mail as unread on the PC, i see "1 mail unread" and look on my Notebook, i see "0 mails unread" :-(

The same problem with moving mails, sometimes i move completed mails to the archiv folder. When i look at the other system, i can see the message in inbox. Now comes the most interesting, if i go in Thunderbird to the inbox properties and click "repair", then the problem is solved.

I have told these problem in german Forums, but many people told me, that these problem are a Thunderbird problem, but i have tested it with other accounts (example, t-online) and a other systems (Kerio server) and there exists no such problem.

I hope, someone understand my broken english and can help me with these problem :-)

Greetings from Germany,
Dominik